# Sum columns row-wise based on IDs in another vector

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have two input data frames, first is called "Firms_Ind" containing 2 columns ("Firms", "Industry") with multiple rows. It gives the industry ID for each Firm. The other one is called "ann_returns" which has as many columns as "Firms_Ind" has rows and with multiple rows. It contains the return for each of the firms (columns) per year (rows).

I want to calculate the annual mean return per industry. So I want an output matrix which has the dimensions: number of column = number of years and number of rows = number of years. For each industry (column) the mean return per year should be calculated.

here is a small example:

```
> Firms_Ind
  Firms Industry
1     A        1
2     B        2
3     C        3
4     D        1
5     E        2
6     F        1

> ann_returns
      A    B    C    D    E    F
y1 0.20 0.11 0.13 0.30 0.24 0.03
y2 0.23 0.08 0.03 0.23 0.17 0.01
y3 0.28 0.19 0.11 0.21 0.19 0.07

> Industry_mean
            1    2    3
y1_means 0.20 0.11 0.13
y2_means 0.23 0.08 0.03
y3_means 0.28 0.19 0.11
```

Comment: Did you try reshaping `ann_returns` into long format, then merge `Firms_Ind` to it, then group by industry to calculate the mean?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method with `sapply`

```
# get a list of firms by industry
inds <- split(Firms_Ind$Firms, Firms_Ind$Industry)
# loop through industries to calculate annual means
myMat <- sapply(inds,
              function(i) if(length(i) > 1) rowMeans(ann_returns[, i]) else ann_returns[, i])
```

Here, `sapply` loops through the industries. For each industry, check if there is more than one firm, if yes, apply `rowMeans`, if no, return the original value.

This returns

```
myMat
           1     2    3
y1 0.1766667 0.175 0.13
y2 0.1566667 0.125 0.03
y3 0.1866667 0.190 0.11
```

**data**

```
Firms_Ind <-
structure(list(Firms = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Industry = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Firms", "Industry"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

ann_returns <- 
structure(c(0.2, 0.23, 0.28, 0.11, 0.08, 0.19, 0.13, 0.03, 0.11, 
0.3, 0.23, 0.21, 0.24, 0.17, 0.19, 0.03, 0.01, 0.07), .Dim = c(3L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("y1", "y2", "y3"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E", "F")))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This seems to be the solution I am looking for. Though, if I run it with my actual data frames, the following error occurs:

Error in `[.data.frame`(ROE_ac, , i) : undefined columns selected 

My data frames: ann_returns is ROE_ac ( R=305, C = 2) and Firms_Ind is firms_FF (R=30, C = 305)

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

Industry_mean <- ann_returns %>% 
         gather(key=Firms,value=value,-Year) %>% #convert to long format
         left_join(Firms_Ind) %>% #merge with firms_ind
         group_by(Year,Industry) %>% #group as required
         summarise(mean=mean(value)) %>% #calculate means
         spread(key=Industry,value=mean) #convert back to wide format

Industry_mean

   Year       `1`   `2`   `3`
* <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    y1 0.1766667 0.175  0.13
2    y2 0.1566667 0.125  0.03
3    y3 0.1866667 0.190  0.11
```

Answer (score 1):

We can split the `ann_returns` by column and then run `rowMeans`:

```
# if Firms in correct order
inds <- split.default(ann_returns, f = Firms_Ind$Industry)

# # if Firms not in correct order:
# inds <- split.default(
#     ann_returns,
#     f = Firms_Ind$Industry[match(colnames(ann_returns), Firms_Ind$Firms)])

do.call(cbind, lapply(inds,rowMeans))
#            1     2    3
# y1 0.1766667 0.175 0.13
# y2 0.1566667 0.125 0.03
# y3 0.1866667 0.190 0.11
```

The two input data.frames are:

```
# > dput(ann_returns)
structure(list(A = c(0.2, 0.23, 0.28), B = c(0.11, 0.08, 0.19
), C = c(0.13, 0.03, 0.11), D = c(0.3, 0.23, 0.21), E = c(0.24, 
0.17, 0.19), F = c(0.03, 0.01, 0.07)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F"), row.names = c("y1", "y2", "y3"), class = "data.frame")
# > dput(Firms_Ind)
structure(list(Firms = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Industry = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Firms", "Industry"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: thanks! what exactly do you mean, by if firms are in correct order?

Comment: @Tobi1990, I mean whether the column names of `ann_returns` is in the same order with the Firm column of `Firms_Ind` so that you can directly split without matching Firm names first.

Comment: yes it is. Thanks again, your solutions works perfectly!

Comment: could you tell me how I can create a new data frame, which contains the calculated industry mean for each firm which is of the industry. So something like ann_returns, but with equal values for firms of the same industry: so that eg A, D, and F would be 0.1766667 for year one

Comment: You can try `res <- Industry_mean[, Firms_Ind$Industry]; colnames(res) <- Firms_Ind$Frims`.